# Why isn't onPreferenceChange being called if it's inside a ScrollView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I've been seeing some strange behavior for preference keys with ScrollView. If I put the `onPreferenceChange` inside the `ScrollView` it won't be called, but if I put it outside it does!

---

I've setup a width preference key as follows:

```swift
struct WidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat(0)

    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

The following simple view does not print:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Hello")
                .preference(key: WidthPreferenceKey.self, value: 20)
                .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self) {
                    print($0) // Not being called, we're in a scroll view.
                }
        }
    }
}
```

But this works:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Hello")
                .preference(key: WidthPreferenceKey.self, value: 20)
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self) {
            print($0)
        }
    }
}
```

---

I know that I can use the latter approach to fix this, but sometimes I'm inside a child view that does not have access to its parent scroll view but I still want to record a preference key.

Any ideas on how to get `onPreferenceChange` to get called inside a `ScrollView`?

> **Note:** I get `Bound preference WidthPreferenceKey tried to update multiple times per frame.` when I put the function inside the scroll view, which might explain what is going on but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like an issue of ScrollView, because replacing it with any other container, even List, in the provided example works perfectly.

Comment: What version of xcode were you on? I had working code using preference keys inside a scroll view in xcode 11.1 when I updated to 11.3 this morning it broke, with this error :/

Answer (score 19):

I had been trying to figure out this issue for a long time and have found how to deal with it, although the way I used was just one of the workarounds.

> Use `onAppear` to `ScrollView` with a flag to make its children show up.

```
...
@State var isShowingContent = false
...

ScrollView {
    if isShowingContent {
        ContentView()
    }
}
.onAppear {
     self.isShowingContent = true
}
```

Or,

Use `List` instead of it.
It has the scroll feature, and you can customize it with its own functionality and UITableView appearance in terms of UI. the most important is that it works as we expected.

**[If you have time to read more]**
Let me say my thought about that issue.

I have confirmed that `onPreferenceChange` isn't called at the **bootstrap** time of a view put inside a `ScrollView`. I'm not sure if it is the right behavior or not. But, I assume that it's wrong because `ScrollView` has to be capable of containing any views even if some of those use PreferenceKey to pass any data among views inside it. If it's the right behavior, it would be quite easy for us to get in trouble when creating our custom views.

Let's get into more detail.
I suppose that `ScrollView` would work slightly different from the other container views such as List, (H/V)Stack when it comes to set up its child view at the bootstrap time. In other words, `ScrollView` would try to draw(or lay out) children in its own way. Unfortunately, that way would affect the children's layout mechanism working incorrectly as what we've been seeing. We could guess what happened with the following message on debug view.

> `TestHPreferenceKey tried to update multiple times per frame.`

It might be a piece of evidence to tell us that the update of children has occurred while `ScrollView` is doing something for its setup. At that moment, it could be guessed that the update to PreferenceKey has been ignored.

That's why I tried to put the placing child views off to `onAppear`.

I hope that will be useful for someone who's struggling with various issues on SwiftUI.

Comment: It also happens with a ZStack (which gets firstly sized by a Color.clear element in it, though making the ZStack as big as its container). Therefore I am not quite sure your reasoning about the ScrollView makes so much sense.

Comment: This did not work for me, but I agree, there is something messed up in ScrollView's bootstrap. The solution to my problem was found in M Wilm's answer around equatability of the preference key's value.

Comment: This worked for me and seems like a bug.  Have you filed one with Apple?  I have confirmed this is still an issue on Xcode 12 beta 6

Comment: This has worked with me, but in case the view is about to be redrawn due to any state changes, the `isShowingContent` variable will be reverted to false resulting in hiding the view

Comment: @JAHelia As far as i know, `State` variable isn't reset unless the base view get rebuilt. In the case of rebuilding the base view, I assume that ScrollView will be recreated and the `onAppear` will be also called again. (I haven't tested yet. sorry)

Comment: @KyokookHwang it actually happened with me many times, yes the base view got redrawn (and this is highly anticipated in SwiftUI for any kind of reason) but the onAppear doesn't get called, resulted in resulting `isShowingContent` to false and hence hiding the scrollView

Comment: @JAHelia @JAHelia Please check this code out. https://gist.github.com/fullc0de/75196f3a67e46992d1220a38057a2cf8.  You can find two buttons when you run this code on Playground. the first button is used to update a state variable declared at a view where has a content view on which `onAppear` is put. the other one is used to control visibility of the view that the first button is involved.  (continue to the next comment)

Comment: You can find that `InnerView` is still shown although you update the counter state by touching the `inc inner count` button. that shows you redrawing the contents of `OuterView` doesn't affect `isShowingInner` state variable. Secondary, you can find that `onAppear` is being called every time when you touch `inc base count` that triggers to redraw `OuterView`. it shows that `onAppear` gets called when `OuterView` gets totally redrawn.  I was afraid that I might be talking in wrong direction to you so please let me see what your code is in principle.

Comment: Using `List` instead of `ScrollView` fixed it for me on 10.15. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think onPreferenceChange in your example is not called because it’s function is profoundly different from preference(key…)

preference(key:..) sets a preference value for the view it is used on.
whereas onPreferenceChange is a function called on a parent view – a view on a higher position in the view tree hierarchy. Its function is to go through all its children and sub-children and collect their preference(key:) values. When it found one it will use the reduce function from the PreferenceKey on this new value and all the already collected values. Once it has all the values collected and reduced them it will execute the onPreference closure on the result.

In your first example this closure is never called because the Text(“Hello”) view has no children which set the preference key value (in fact the view has no children at all). In your second example the Scroll view has a child which sets its preference value (the Text view).

All this does not explain the multiple times per frame error – which is most likely unrelated.

Recent update (24.4.2020):
In a similar case I could induce the call of onPreferenceChange by changing the Equatable condition for the PreferenceData. PreferenceData needs to be Equatable (probably to detect a change in them). However, the Anchor type by itself is not equatable any longer. To extract the values enclosed in an Anchor type a GeometryProxy is required. You get a GeometryProxy via a GeometryReader. For not disturbing the design of views by enclosing some of them into a GeometryReader I generated one in the equatable function of the PreferenceData struct:

```
struct ParagraphSizeData: Equatable {
  let paragraphRect: Anchor<CGRect>?

  static func == (value1: ParagraphSizeData, value2: ParagraphSizeData) -> Bool {

    var theResult : Bool = false
    let _ = GeometryReader { geometry in
       generateView(geometry:geometry, equality:&theResult)
    }

    func generateView(geometry: GeometryProxy, equality: inout Bool) -> Rectangle {
       let paragraphSize1, paragraphSize2: NSSize

      if let anAnchor = value1.paragraphRect { paragraphSize1 = geometry[anAnchor].size }
       else {paragraphSize1 = NSZeroSize }
       if let anAnchor = value2.paragraphRect { paragraphSize2 = geometry[anAnchor].size }
       else {paragraphSize2 = NSZeroSize }

       equality = (paragraphSize1 == paragraphSize2)
       return Rectangle()
    }

   return theResult     
  }

}
```

With kind regards

Comment: I have a similar situation and what you describe does not seem to be the case. Values are actually "collected", it's just that onPreferenceChange is not called with those values. Furthermore, when I start scrolling the view, onPreferenceChange is called, but not before that.

Comment: I just spent a few days on this problem. Your answer was the solution. However, I store the GeometryProxy as property of the `ParagraphSizeData`, and use that to compute the bounds of the anchors. The content lambda of the GeometryReader will never get called otherwise.

Comment: This is a great answer. Been chasing a non-updating preferenceKey and it was to do with my equatable check only using ID and not the rect. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I think this is because you implemented `reduce()` incorrectly.

You can find the details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73300115/4366470

TL;DR: Replace `value = nextValue()` in `reduce()` with `value += nextValue()`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the issue is not necessarily with `ScrollView`, but with your usage of `PreferenceKey`. For instance, here is a sample struct in which a `PreferenceKey` is set according to the width of a `Rectangle`, and then printed using `.onPreferenceChange()`, all inside of a `ScrollView`. As you drag the `Slider` to change the width, the key is updated and the print closure is executed.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var width: CGFloat = 100

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Slider(value: $width, in: 100...200)

            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                Rectangle()
                    .background(WidthPreferenceKeyReader())
                    .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self) {
                        print($0)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: self.width)
        }
    }
}

struct WidthPreferenceKeyReader: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.clear)
                .preference(key: WidthPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size.width)
        }
    }
}
```

As you noted, the first time the key tries to set, the console prints "Bound preference WidthPreferenceKey tried to update multiple times per frame," but a real value is immediately set afterward, and it continues to update dynamically.

What value are you actually trying to set, and what are you trying to do in `.onPreferenceChange()`?

Comment: I'm trying to get the width of the smallest child and set the parent view to that width. I'll ask it as a new question

Comment: FYI, It occurs when you try to update the width at the startup time. not update it by input events like the slider.

Answer (score 2):

You may only read it in superView, but you can change it with `transformPreference` after you set it .

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        VStack{
        Text("Hello")
            .preference(key: WidthPreferenceKey.self, value: 20)
        }.transformPreference(WidthPreferenceKey.self, {
        $0 = 30})
    }.onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self) {
        print($0)
    }
}
}
```

The last value is `30` now. Hope it is what you want.

You can read from other layer:

```
  ScrollView {

        Text("Hello").preference(key: WidthPreferenceKey.self, value: CGFloat(40.0))
            .backgroundPreferenceValue(WidthPreferenceKey.self) { x -> Color in
               print(x)
                return Color.clear
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Although this works, as I said in the question I don't have access to the parent scroll view and I need a solution to read the value from inside the scroll view.

Comment: You can hook on preference on any outer super view,

Comment: I can't hook onPreferenceChange to any outer super view. Say the scroll view is given to you, i.e. something like `var body: some View { ScrollView { MyView() } }`. You only have access to `MyView` to play around with. Even if you add a `VStack` in `MyView` it won't work.

Comment: You can read from overlay or background. Although I don't know what is your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is actually not in `ScrollView` but in usage - this mechanism allow to transfer data up in viewTree:

> A view with multiple children automatically combines its values for a
> given preference into a single value visible to its ancestors.

[source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preferencekey)

The keywords here - **`with multiple children`**. This mean that u can pass it in viewTree from child to parent.

Let's review u'r code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Hello")
                .preference(key: WidthPreferenceKey.self, value: 20)
                .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self) {
                    print($0) // Not being called, we're in a scroll view.
                }
        }
    }
}
```

As u can see now - child pass value to itself, and not to parent - so this don't want to work, as per design.

And working case:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Hello")
                .preference(key: WidthPreferenceKey.self, value: 20)
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self) {
            print($0)
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `ScrollView` is parent and `Text` is child, and child talk to parent - everything works as expected.

So, as I sad in the beginning the problem here not in ScrollView but in usage and in Apple documentation (u need to read it few times as always).

---

And regarding this:

> Bound preference `WidthPreferenceKey` tried to update multiple times per
> frame.

This is because u may change multiply values in same time and View can't be rendered, try to `.receive(on:)` or `DispatchQueue.main.async` as workaround (I guess this may be a bug)

Comment: This is the best answer