# SwiftUI - onPreferenceChange is not called

Tags: swiftui

I was trying to understand how preference and onPreferenceChange works, so I was experimenting with a few hierarchies, unfortunately I am stuck right now on one situation where onPreferenceChange is not called anymore. 
What is strange to me, is fact, when I (on the bottom of TestView struct) remove lines

*.modifier(Border(.column))*
OR
*Spacer(minLength: 0)*

onPreferenceChange starts working normaly/is called as I expect

I was trying to find explanation, but with no success. Can anyone explain to me, what I am doing wrong?

Here is code of my root view

```
public struct MyRootView: View {

    public var body: some View {
        TestView()
        .onPreferenceChange(ChangeInfoKey.self) { changeInfo in
            print("preference changed: \(changeInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

TestView:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var changeInfo: ChangeInfo?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                Button(action: {
                    self.changeInfo = ChangeInfo(title: "Some Title \(Int.random(in: 0...10))")
                    print("Change initiated: \(self.changeInfo!.title) - \(self.changeInfo!.id)")
                }) {
                    Text("My Button")
                }
                .preference(key: ChangeInfoKey.self, value: changeInfo)
            }
            .modifier(Border(.column))
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Border modifier creates only visual border around view, I am not sure, if its relevant with this issue, but for those, who want to see completely all parts of my code, or try it:

```
struct Border: ViewModifier {

    enum BorderType: RawRepresentable {
        case section
        case emptyColumn
        case column
        case widget
        case debug

        var rawValue: (CGFloat, CGFloat, Color) {
            switch self {
            case .section: return (2, 0, Color.blue)
            case .emptyColumn: return (0.5, 4, Color(0xa7afb5))
            case .column: return (0.5, 4, Color(0xa7afb5))
            case .widget: return (0.5, 2, Color(0xa7afb5))
            case .debug: return (4, 0, Color.red)
            }
        }

        init?(rawValue: (CGFloat, CGFloat, Color)) {
            fatalError("ElementBorder.init(rawValue) - not implemented")
        }
    }

    let lineWidth: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    let dashLength: CGFloat

    init(_ borderType: BorderType) {
        self.lineWidth = borderType.rawValue.0
        self.dashLength = borderType.rawValue.1
        self.color = borderType.rawValue.2
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if dashLength > 0 {
            return AnyView(content
                .overlay(
                    Rectangle()
                        .strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: self.lineWidth, dash: [self.dashLength]))
                        .foregroundColor(self.color)
            ))
        } else {
            return AnyView(content
                .border(self.color, width: self.lineWidth)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58720495/why-isnt-onpreferencechange-being-called-if-its-inside-a-scrollview-in-swiftui

Comment: Thank You a lot, I read it a few times (lots of good informations). Unfortunately it doesn't explain, why onPreferenceChange is not called when Spacer is added into VStack after Group (and if this spacer is removed, onPreferenceChange starts working)

Comment: That's true, I also encounter lots of strange behaviours in SwiftUI. Hope that Apple will come up with better documentation soon...

Comment: What does the `reduce()` of `ChangeInfoKey` look like? I also got the similar problem, and Apple answered me it was expected since I implemented it wrongly. Details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73300115/4366470