# onPreferenceChange not called when Parent View has a Date Picker, SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have one parent View which has two Child views.

When the child view changes the preference value, the parent receives the preference changes via `onPreferenceChange`
However, when the parent has a Date Picker, `onPreferenceChange` doesn't get called and stops working.
Has anyone found any workaround for this ?

```
struct parentView: View {

@State private var date = Date()

var body: some View {
    
    VStack{
        
        ChildView1()
        
        Text("Child View 2")
    
       // DatePicker("", selection: self.$date, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
       

    }
    .onPreferenceChange(testPreference.self, perform: { value in
        print("Printing preference value")
        print(value)
    })
 }
}


struct ChildView1: View {

@State private var tablets : Int = 0

var body: some View {
    Text("Child View 1")
        .onTapGesture {
            self.tablets = self.tablets + 1
        }
        .preference(key: testPreference.self, value: self.tablets)

  }
}


struct testPreference: PreferenceKey {

typealias Value = Int

static var defaultValue: Int = 0

static func reduce(value: inout Int, nextValue: () -> Int) {
    value = nextValue()
  }
}
```

Comment: This has to be a SwiftUI bug (reproduced in 12.0.1). I recommend opening a feedback on it. The only fix I've found so far is to move the `.onPreferenceChange` from the `VStack` to `ChildView1()`. Even putting it on the `Text` bizarrely doesn't work. Burying the DatePicker in a sub-container also doesn't work. It feels like it's pointing to some kind of hack inside of DatePicker.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your workaround seems to work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also got stuck on the same problem and Apple told me this was expected.
Our fault is we implemented this `reduce()` incorrectly:

```swift
static func reduce(value: inout Int, nextValue: () -> Int) {
    value = nextValue()
}
```

This overwrites values explicitly written by views, by the default value written by every view. Therefore, you need to rewrite that function so that applying it to the default value has no effect, as described in the documentation of [PreferenceKey.defaultValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preferencekey/defaultvalue-11lde):

> Views that have no explicit value for the key produce this default value. Combining child views may remove an implicit value produced by using the default. **This means that reduce(value: &x, nextValue: {defaultValue}) shouldn’t change the meaning of x.**

So you'd need to replace this line:

```swift
value = nextValue()
```

with this:

```swift
value = max(value, nextValue())
```

or this:

```swift
value += nextValue()
```

or something like that.

Comment: been stuck on this for 2 days!! Thank-you sir