# How to have a reusable scroll like UITableView or UICollectionView in SwiftUI that support all scroll APIs and also indexPathForItem(at:)?

Tags: ios, list, uitableview, swiftui, scrollview

My Goal:
I want to have a reusable scroll like UiTableview in SwiftUI to load views that are not in the same Height sizes also want to control the scroll. Something like Instagram Explore view. Basically, the data source will grow as user scroll more. So I can benefit from the following:

- Item Reusability
- Scroll To a point
- Get the [index](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618030-indexpathforitem) or id of an item at CGPoint
- ScrollToItem
- Creating snapping to a point based on [Drags](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619436-scrollviewdidenddragging) and [Deceleration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619417-scrollviewdidenddecelerating)
- Memory-optimized

My minimum target for this project is iOS 15.

**ScrollView**:

I tried `ScrollView` with `ScrollViewReader`, but even if I use the `LazyVStack` it will not perform well in case of memory,`LazyVStack` will create a view when it is needed but after that, it will stay in memory. Also, I can not scroll to a CGPoint, just to the predefined Id.

I can not use `.content.offset` because then the ScrollViewReader stops working. Also, by using `.content`, the `ScrolView` loads all the data at once in memory. I can not get the benefits of controlling its offset.

`ScrollView` with `lazyVGrid` doesn't perform well when I want to control the scrollView; it causes so many jumps and unwanted lags and also the same issue that I can not control so much on Scroll and drags. [apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvgrid) suggests this combination for loading a long list, but again you can not control it because it is based on ScrollView.

Adding Drag gesture as `.simultaneousGesture` to scrollView to get drags is only possible if I set the `minimumDistance = 0.0`, which means ScrollView will not scroll anymore. so I can not have the combination of scroll and accessing the velocity of user drags.

**List**:

The list is good in memory and reusability, although you will have the same issues regarding the scroll. But it has another big disadvantage. `ScrollViewReader` is not well supported for `List`. it causes **crashes** in the app., there are a lot of threads in apple forums and StackOverflow that mention this problem.
[StackOverFlow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309333/swiftui-crash-when-calling-scrollto-method-with-anchor-center). [apple thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/712510).

I have been working to solve this issue for 2 weeks, but all of them lead me to the point that SwiftUi is not powerful enough for large projects to create an enterprise app that works smoothly and reliably.

So is there any good solution to using SwiftUI for these problems?

Comment: My gut feel is that this isn't something you can do with pure SwiftUI yet. You can either use `UICollectionView` with a custom layout (you can embed this in a SwiftUI hierarchy with `UIViewRepresentable`. You can also take a look at [IGListKit](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit)

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, It seems that SwiftUI is moving too slowly. Although SwiftUI has many advantages, it will put you down when you want to take it seriously. Maybe the best option is to have the base project based on UIKit and use the benefits of SwiftUI whenever you want by using `UIHostingController`.

Comment: I believe that using ScrollReader and LazyVStack would do what you're looking for. What is it that you need to get the item at a point for?

Comment: @Fogmeister Thanks for your suggestion, but as I mentioned about memory, `LazyVStack` just does not create a view unless needed. After that, it will stay in memory. Now imagine you load 100 Post views containing some media items based on pagination, when you reach 100 Posts, it consumes a lot of memory. on the other hand, I want to control how user scroll to implement snapping.